# importing database from localhost to AWS RDS?

Tags: 14.04, mysql, phpmyadmin, aws

I've tried to export database from AWS RDS to localhost by command line it works
the command is

```
mysqlump -h r.rds.server -u rdsusername -p  rdsdatabase > backupfile.dump
```

but it doesn't works for importing database from localhost to AWS RDS the command is

```
mysqlump -h r.rds.server -u rdsusername -p  rdsdatabase  backupfile.dump
```

after running this command mysql generate report that dump is completed but in RDS AWS no database has been imported.

Can you help me come out from this scenario??

Answer (score 0):

Your import command is missing the `<`.

```
mysqlump -h r.rds.server -u rdsusername -p  rdsdatabase < backupfile.dump
```

Answer (score 0):

1-Connect to your RDS instance:

```
mysql -h <host_name> -P 3306 -u <db_master_user> -p
```

2-For SQL format, use the following command:

```
mysql> source backupfile.dump;
```